# Best method to use external templates with knockout

Tags: templates, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have built a html page with some internal templates. See url jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hoven002/jQTDH/

What is the best method to make the templates external and how?

Regards,
Kenneth

Answer (score 5):

The best method, in my opinion, is to use this plugin: https://github.com/ifandelse/Knockout.js-External-Template-Engine.

It enables a new template engine that will pull templates from external files.  It has some configuration options as well to determine where the templates are pulled from.

Comment: Thanks Ryan,

So I have to put this in my HTML:

<script src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/TrafficCop-amd.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/infuser-amd.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js"></script>
And then I can make external template files. Do I have to use jquery-tmpl or can I use only the template engine?

Do you know if there (in Fiddle) is an example of the above mentioned method?

Comment: If you use the `_all.js` version, then you should not need TrafficCop or infuser, as they are included.  Otherwise, you have it right.  Not sure if there is a fiddle, because the AJAX part is hard to fake.  There is an example in the repository though.

Comment: You do not need to use jQuery Templates either.  You can use the native templates.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a function that loads templates, without any dependency but jQuery. You must mark each `<script>` tags you want to be dynamically loaded with the attribute `data-template-src` and put there the path of your HTML file. Following is the code and an example.

Warning: since it uses AJAX to load templates, it needs an HTTP server (it won't work locally with `file://` protocol)

## /main.js

```
// Loads all the templates defined with the tag data-template-src.
// Returns a promise that fulfills when all the loads are done.
function loadTemplates() {
    var templateLoads = [];

    $('[data-template-src]').each(function () {
        var templateElement = $(this);
        var templateUrl = templateElement.attr('data-template-src');

        // Load the template into the element and push the promise to do that into the templateLoads array
        templateLoads.push(
            $.get(templateUrl)
            .done(function (data) {
                templateElement.html(data);
            })
        );
    });

    return $.when.apply($, templateLoads);
}

// When all templates are loaded, apply bindings
loadTemplates().done(function () {
    ko.applyBindings({}, document.getElementById("htmlDoc"));
});
```

## /index.html

```
<html id="htmlDoc">
  <body>
    <div data-bind="template: { name: 'exampleTemplate' }"></div>
    <script type="text/html" id="exampleTemplate" data-template-src="/assets/exampleTemplate.html"></script>

    <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/knockout.js"></script>
    <script src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## /assets/exampleTemplate.html

```
<h1>Hello world</h1>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'exampleSubTemplate' }"></div>
```

## /assets/exampleSubTemplate.html

```
<h2>How do you do?</h2>
```